# How to prevent duplicate calls on refresh

Tags: spring-cloud

i have refreshscope bean with a constructor which is calling x method which will be invoked on initialization by spring.
Upon /actuator/refresh, this bean is getting detached. on next first request to x method the bean is getting initialized which in turn causing x method to run again. is there any way to resolve it (without duplicating x method by different names).

Comment: That's the point of refresh scope, beans get reinitialized. Sounds like you shouldn't have that bean be in refresh scope

Comment: i need refresh scope for one of property

Comment: Can you use use `@ConfigurationProperties`?

Comment: let me correct, i need refresh for both property and bean itself. my bean is singleton, i cannot use `@ConfigurationProperties`

Comment: Then you'll have to keep some static state somewhere